# Parsing a distorted HTML page in php

Tags: php, html, ajax, html-parsing

I'm calling an AJAX url in php file and getting its contents through CURL. 
But the HTML I'm getting is full of \r,\t and \n.Divs have also been distorted.
How do I deal with this. Here is a small portion of the full HTML text.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
id=
"\&quot;moreCount\&quot;">491-500</span>\r\n\r\n\r\n\t
<div id="\&quot;propSearchMainWrap\&quot;">\r\n\t\t
<div class="\&quot;propSearchMainContent\&quot;">\r\n\t\t\t
<div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t
<div class="\&quot;searchDtlLeftN\&quot;" style="\&quot;width:">
\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<input type=
"\'checkbox\'" name=
"\'checkbox10374276\'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tid=\'checkbox10374276\'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tonmouseout=\&quot;hideToolTipCheckboxCount(\'tool_tip10374276\');\&quot;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tonmouseover=\&quot;showToolTipCheckboxCount(\'tool_tip10374276\',\'Property\');\&quot;">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t
<div id="\'tool_tip10374276\'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tstyle=\'display:"
width:="" position:="" z-index:="" padding:=""></div>
\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t <b><a target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" href=
"/&quot;/propertyDetails/5-BHK-3000-Sq-ft-Residential-House-FOR-Sale-Cookes-Town-in-Bangalore&amp;id=Q8oDBbaV2WFzpSvf+uAgZw==/&quot;">
5 BHK Residential House for Sale in Cookes
Town</a>\r\n\t\t\t\t</b>\r\n\t\t\t</div>
\r\n\t\t\t
<!-- added by narendra -->\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t
<div style="\&quot;width:"></div>
\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t
<!-- added by narendra -->\r\n\t\t</div>
\r\n\t\t
<div>\r\n\t\t\t<!--left panel start-->\r\n\t\t\t
<div class="\&quot;searchDetailPanelLft\&quot;">\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t
<div class="\&quot;searchDetailSubBox1\&quot;">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t
<!--content start-->\r\n\t\t\t\t\t
<div class="\&quot;search_packageImg\&quot;">
\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img alt="\&quot;Premium\&quot;"
title=
"\&quot;Premium\&quot;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tsrc=\&quot;/images/premium-img.gif\&quot;">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>
```

Comment: I think it's a lot to do to get some useful content out of that mess. The better solution would be to work on the PHP-script to get clean HTML.

Comment: WTF... not sure how you've managed that, or what that tag-less `id` attribute is after `body`...

Comment: @Utkanos That would have been mistakenly pasted .The main concern in the \r ,\n and \t text appearing in the entire HTML.

Comment: Seems the `\r\n\t` are put in single-quotes, that's why they are coming in the html as characters. Change your file which is called from ajax and put `\r\n\t` in double-quotes to allow them to be parsed, not single quotes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily solved it with stripcslashes() method.
Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

The \r, \t and \n may be removed with preg_replace.

That said, you'll still have strange assignments such as width:= ... is this HTML Pascal?

```
    $html = // awful stuff

    // Remove quoted \r, \t and \n
    $html = preg_replace("#\\[rnt]#ms", '', $html);

    // Remove double quotation marks, apparently spurious
    $html = preg_replace('#["]#ms', '', $html);

    // Remove extra escapes
    $html = stripslashes($html);

    // Convert (apparently) original marks back to normal
    $html = HTML_Entity_Decode($html);
```

Comment: Easily solved it with stripcslashes() method. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to replace all \x -occurrences with the supposed char. Then DOMDocument's loadHTML is good for that.

```
$html = strtr($html, array('\\\\' => '\\', '\\r' => "\r", '\\n' => "\n", '\\t' => "\t", '\\' => ''));
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
```